# store all files name in a variable from directory/subdirectoy unix

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I want to store all the files of *.mk type in a variable from sub directories and then use it in my program. I tried with below command but it's not working.

Shell script:

```
for i in `find . -name *.mk` do
echo $i
done
```

it's showing below error message.
bash: ./make_files.sh: line 6: syntax error near unexpected token `echo'
bash: ./make_files.sh: line 6:`echo $i'

It's not printing anything.

Comment: Either you must a ';' just before "do" or move the "do" to another line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Try either

for i in `find . -name '*.mk'`; do
echo $i
done
```

or

```
for i in `find . -name '*.mk'`
do
     echo $i
done
```

Note the use of quoting, too.